# Separate Applications for iPad1-2 and iPad3-4

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is it possible to restrict applications to only run in iPad3 and iPad4?

I have an application which has memory leak, most probably on iPad 1-2.

I want to restrict my application.

Comment: Are you sure the bug is on a particular hardware version, rather than iOS version? Or does it leak on all devices, but the later iPads have more memory so you don't notice as much? I suggest trying to fix the leak, to be frank. Note that the iPad 2 is still available to buy from Apple.

Comment: If its a memory leak causing limited crashes, its not because of the hardware, its because iPad 1-2 have less memory. Fix the leak, it may not be crashing 3-4 but its still there.

Comment: Responding to the memory leak by limiting the App to certain newer devices is treating the symptoms rather than the root issue. Why not just fix the memory leak? Can you post some code related to the leak? That'll give people a change to try to help resolve the root issue.

Answer (score 3):

Answering to your question, that's not possible right now, you can restrict the version of iOS, but not the device.

About your problem, as other people is saying, fix your code because you are leaking somewhere, you get the risk of Apple rejecting it too.

The best way to check it is analysing your code (Product > Analyze), also run the Instruments (Product > Profile) and check the memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is fixing your leak.
If you still want to restrict usage of your application you can use the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` list. add a capability in your plist called `auto-focus-camera`. This functionality is available starting the 3rd generation iPad. 
Keep in mind that this is not the best option

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/B_DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) is the capabilities list sorted by device